# I am trying to display an image using python and kivy in a popup window but I get this error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, image, popup, kivy

I am trying to display an image using python and kivy in a popup window but I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.
If I put the path manually it works but also if I print it it's the same and I cast it in string as it's required.

```
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        if sys.platform == 'win':
            user_path = dirname(expanduser('~')) + sep + 'Documents'
        else:
            user_path = expanduser('~') + sep + 'Documents'
        browser = FileBrowser(select_string='Select',
                              favorites=[(user_path, 'Documents')])
        browser.bind(
                    on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
                    on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled)
        return browser

    def _fbrowser_canceled(self, instance):
        TestApp.stop(self)

    def _fbrowser_success(self, instance):
        path = str(instance.selection).strip('[]')

        content = Image(source = path)
        popup = Popup(content=content, auto_dismiss=False)
        content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)

        popup.open()

TestApp().run()
```

`#[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file 'C:\\...'.`

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Your code does not run: `NameError: name 'FileBrowser' is not defined`

Comment: Just replace `path = str(instance.selection).strip('[]')` with `path = instance.selection[0]`. Your command is creating a string which is srrounded by quote chars (i.e., quotes inside quotes).

Comment: @JohnAnderson thx that was the problem. I fixed it by adding the quote chars to the strip but I will try your suggestion too.

Comment: The `selection` from `FileBrowser` is a list of strings, so the appropriate way to extract an item from the list is to use the `[]` construct. This also avoids complications that may arise with oddly named files (like files that require embedded quotes or '[]' characters).